# The for loop works on declaring the variable inside it but not in the global scope

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scopes

when I declared the variable that contains the li outside the for loop, the loop only printed one list item . I read about that issue and found that two identical nodes can’t be present in the same place simultaneously , so the loop deletes the created li every time to add the new one (which results at the end in only one list item)

But on declaring the variable in the for loop , the code worked and 4 list items were created . I want to understand what happened programmatically when I declared the variable inside the loop .

I then tried to print the variable of the list item in the console, and it printed the 4 list items . Does that mean the when the loop runs each time , it just updates the value of the listItem variable to include one more list item at a time ?

But how doesn’t a redeclaration of the variable take place ?

The code :

```
let theMenu = document.createElement("ul");
for (let i = 0 ; i <= 3; i++) {
    let listItem = document.createElement("li");
    theMenu.append(listItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens during the for...loop iterations on these two cases:

1. The listItem is a global variable, therefore the menuItem keeps a single reference to one object.

[image]

2. The listItem is a local variable, recreated from scratch on each iteration, therefore the menuItem keeps 3 different object references:

[image]

Hope the visuals (created with [whimsical](https://whimsical.com/)) help to understand the concept of variable scoping inside loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The visuals really helped . And I am curious to know what tools did you use to do these visuals as they would help me a lot in studying .

Comment: @Mohammed I've updated the answer with a link to the tool I've used (whimsical).

Answer (score 0):

An element can only appear in a document once.

If you `append` an element that is already somewhere in the document then it will be *moved* not cloned.

If you place the line `let listItem = document.createElement("li");` outside the loop then you create **one** list item, then append it to the document four times (moving it the second and subsequent times).

If you keep that line inside the loop then you create four list items.